# Set font size for all R-code snippets in knitr Rmd

Tags: r, knitr

How can I set up a font size for all the R-snippets, i.e., globally, in an Rmd file?

I am using the PPT presentation as the output. The relevant header part is, thus:

```
---
...
output:
    powerpoint_presentation:
        reference_doc: template.pptx
––
```

Could I set this up in the `knitr` options? Somewhere here:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo=TRUE, results='markup')
options(width=80, show.signif.stars=FALSE)
```
````

Defining this in the `css` chunk does not seem to work. Like this:

````
```{css, echo=FALSE}
code.r{
    font-size: 12px;
}
```
````

Comment: Here is a question that asks something similar for MS Word and has some answers: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49621914/4303162 Maybe this helps. It seems that the way to go is to modify the appropriate styles in the reference doc.

Comment: This might work with Word but PowerPoint does not appropriate style control. It could also be that being for macOS, PowerPoint is even more crippled.